UFW configuration for load balancers with floating IP
I have an app, which is connected to HAProxy, which in turn is connected to a cluster of 3 SQL servers.  I opened up the UFW firewall at the HAProxy server to allow traffic from the app server private IP on port 80
sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 to any port 80 comment 'http backend'

and the db servers private IP on port 3306.
sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 to any port 3306 comment 'mysql'

All good.
I am adding a floating IP in front of HAProxy, as well as a second HAProxy server to provide redundancy for the load balancers.  Because the floating IP is a public IP address, the only way that the app server can successfully communicate with the db servers is for me to allow traffic from the app server public IP on port 3306.
sudo ufw allow from <Public IP> to any port 3306 comment 'mysql'

Without opening up the public IP, the app server can't communicate with the db server.
The new network setting requires me to have another open port to a public IP address (the db server), which makes me a bit uneasy because I don't prefer to open up a public IP address if its not needed, and to me, it seems to be a less secure configuration compared to before and opening up a potential window for attack.
question for the experience network admin here, is there a more secure way to allow the communication between the app and db servers?  or am i over-worried?
Thanks.

"Because the floating IP is a public IP address..." Where is this hosted? In a typical configuration, the server that hosts the public ip will also have an "inside" address connected to your internal network, and you would grant database access to that internal address, not the public address. Tell us more about the infrastructure you're working with.

The servers and the floating IP address are on Hetzner.  The servers have both public and private IP addresses.  The floating IP address is only public, according to them.
